# UIPageControl dots with larger space in between each dots

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I want have UIPageControl with larger space in between those dots. How can i achieve it.

Normal UiPageControl

[image]

I need this

[image]

Also i don't want to use any third party component. I'm just thinking of doing it via inheriting the default UIPageControl, but i'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check [styledpagecontrol](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/styledpagecontrol) from [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com)

You can customize the way you want. I am using this in many apps.

You can have your own set of images for dots + you can set spacing between two dots.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way of doing it other than using 3rd party controls as of now. Search and use according to your requirements.