# Increase spacing between indicator dots of UIPageControl

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

So I am working on customizing the UIPageControl (which Apple really doesn't make easy) and I'm wondering if there's a way to increase/decrease space between the indicator dots.

I've been using this code to get the UIPageControl

```
var pageControlMaybe: UIPageControl?

for (var i = 0; i < subviews.count; i++) {
    if (subviews[i] is UIPageControl) {
        pageControlMaybe = subviews[i] as? UIPageControl
        break
    }
}
```

But now I'm wondering if there's an easy way to change the spacing?  I can resize the dots with a transform

```
pageControlMaybe?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.4, 1.4)
```

But this also increases the spacing between them.  Ideally it would keep the dot size and just reduce the space between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered [some other times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249305/uipagecontrol-dots-with-larger-space-in-between-each-dots) there's no way to do this. I'd recommend you using 3rd party controls like [FXPageControl](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXPageControl) and use this property:

> @property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat dotSpacing;

Comment: @tbondwilkinson still not xD

Answer (score 10):

First scale pageControl

let scale: CGFloat = 1.5

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
```

This will scale also each dot so you can scale each dot with the following code

```
for dot in pageControl.subviews{
    dot.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1/scale, y: 1/scale)
}
```

A little hacky but works